# Required request part 'file' is not present] springboot client

Tags: spring-boot, post, http-request-parameters

i have this code in client:

```
          RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
          File file = new File("C:\\temp\\aadocejem.doc");
          MultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

          map.add("file", file);


          String result = restTemplate.postForObject(url+"/doc_file", map, String.class);
```

And this code is what you call the above:

```
 @PostMapping("/doc_file")
    public ResponseEntity<File> docFileV1(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile originalDocFile) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(docFileService.processDocFile(originalDocFile));

    }
```

The error it gives me on the server: Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]

The error it gives me in the client: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : [{"timestamp":"2020-04-23T10:55:32.258+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","trace":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServlet... (5758 bytes)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work with postForObject.

Use postForEntity instead:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART__FORM__DATA);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
body.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url+"/doc_file", requestEntity, String.class);
```

Comment: I changed it and it keeps giving me the same error: Could not resolve parameter [0] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.io.File> com.n.poc.controller.PocController.docFileV1(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile): Required request part 'file' is not present

Comment: You probably have to enclose the file in a Resource. body.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file)); I updated the answer